# What is this show about a lion statue in (probably) Venice?

Tags: story-identification

I barely remember this show/movie since I only saw it when I was very young, but I *seem* to remember it was a television series rather than a movie. I'm not even sure of the genre, but I suppose it could be called fantasy, if just barely.

The only thing I definitely remember about it is that there was a statue of a lion holding a book (presumably the [Lion of Saint Mark](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion_of_Saint_Mark)) that was somehow special. As far as I remember, once every century, or something like that, a page in the book would turn, and something special would happen (possibly only to those who saw it).

I'm pretty sure I saw it on television some time in the mid- to late eighties. All I remember is a young boy/man looking up at the statue, and a shot of the statue with a turning page. I'm pretty sure it was on a large square, probably in Venice.

Does anyone know what this is?

Comment: This website doesn't support BB codes. Take a look [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/editing-help) for markdown support

Comment: Was the show in English?

Comment: Do you remember if it was animated or live action? If animated, do you remember anything about the style?

Comment: Live action. I don't remember if it was in English, but I suppose so.

Comment: _[Voyagers!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voyagers!)_ had a book with turning pages in the credits, and a boy as a main character, but doesn't otherwise match your description. We don't know when you were very young, so there's no way to tell when you saw the show.

Comment: The lions aren't [Patience and Fortitude](https://www.nypl.org/help/about-nypl/library-lions) by any chance? They're not _holding_ books, but they're _in front of_ a lot of them! Plus there's a square / plaza.

Answer (score 5):

Was this on Belgian television? If so, it could be *Het geheim van de leeuw van Venetie*, (*The secret of the lion of Venice*) after a book by Kitty Leibovitch. The son of the Belgian Consul in Venice notices the lion on the St.-Marc square bell tower turning a page of the book it is holding, but nobody believes him. A treasure hunt ensues. More information on https://www.televisiegeheugen.nl/televisieseries-en-programmas/geheim-van-de-leeuw-van-veneti%C3%AB-het-1981.

A 3 part television series from the eighties. Found by searching with the Dutch phrase `belgische ambassadeur venetie leeuw met boek`, since I remember the scene from Belgian television in the 80ies, and my memory added his father being an ambassador.